# How do i union or join multiple tables with multiple where clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I have two tables one is 'member' and another is 'savings'. the member table is below:

```
id|DomainName|DivisionName|ZoneName|MemberId|GeneralSaving
 1|  hem     | raj        | raj    |1111    |100
 2|  hem     | raj        | bog    |2222    |100
 3|  edu     | dha        | dha    |3333    |100
 4|  edu     | dha        | nara   |4444    |100
 5|  busi    | dha        | gazi   |5555    |100
 6|  busi    | raj        | raj    |6666    |100
```

and the 'savings' table is as below:

```
id|DomainName|DivisionName|ZoneName|MemberId|DPS|Month|Year|AccounNo
 1|  hem     | raj        | raj    |1111    |100|jan  |2017|11111
 2|  hem     | raj        | bog    |2222    |150|jan  |2017|22221
 3|  edu     | dha        | dha    |3333    |200|jan  |2017|33331
 4|  edu     | dha        | nara   |4444    |250|jan  |2017|44441
 5|  busi    | dha        | gazi   |5555    |300|jan  |2017|55551
```

Here, ZoneName is subset of DivisionName, DivisionName is subset of DomainName. Sometimes just DomainName is given, sometimes DomainName and DivisionName are given and Most of the time DomainName, DivisionName, ZoneName these three are given. I need to post the GeneralSaving of 'member' and DPS of 'savings' after joining two tables, obviously i can't post the same month data. A person can have more than two or three account no, though account no is unique. Now How can I join or union of the two table in laravel 5.2 ?

the output will be as below:
DomainName = hem, DivisionName=raj, ZoneName=raj, Month=Feb, Year=2017

```
MemberId|AccountNo|GeneralSaving|DPS
1111    |11111    |100          |100
2222    |22221    |100          |150
```

if DomainName = busi, DivisionName = dha, Month=Feb, Year=2017

```
MemberId|AccountNo|GeneralSaving|DPS
5555    |55551    |100          |300
6666    |         |100          |
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: DomainName, DivisionName, ZoneName, Month, Year will be given, I want all MembrId, AccountNo, GeneralSaving, DPS

Comment: No, this doesn't help us to help you.  Please show the output you expect from your two tables.

Comment: please see now, I have given the output as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.....

```
    SELECT s.MemberId, s.AccounNo, s.DPS, m.GeneralSaving
    FROM member m
    JOIN savings s ON CASE WHEN $DomainName != null THEN s.DomainName = $DomainName END 
    AND CASE WHEN $DivisionName != null THEN s.DivisionName = $DivisionName END
    AND CASE WHEN $ZoneName != null THEN s.ZoneName = $ZoneName END
```

Here $DomainName , $DivisionName, $ZoneName are user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5 the sql of above query will be as follows:

```
DB::table('member')
    ->leftjoin('savings', 'savings.MemberId', '=', 'member.MemberId')
    ->select('member.MemberId', 'savings.AccountNo', 'member.GeneralSaving', 'savings.Dps')
    ->where('savings.DomainName', '=', $DomainName)
    ->where('savings.DivisionName', '=', $DivisionName)
    ->where('savings.Month', '=', $Month)->where('savings.Year', '=', $Year)
    ->get
```

This query has been tested in laravel 5 and it has worked